# Add a tab(item) to tabpanel by button clicking, extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a tabpanel, that initially has 1 tab and a button. But the user should be able to add more tabs by clicking on the button. Here is the code so far:

```
var tabPan = Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
listeners: {
    beforetabchange: function(tabs, newTab, oldTab, eOpts) {
        if (newTab.title=='Add') { // Or some other condition

            return false; 
        }
    }
},
items:[
{
  title: 'Default Tab',
  html: innerHtml  
},
{
  xtype: 'button',
  title : 'Add',
},
]
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is right, All you need is to create a panel and add it to the TabPanel.

```
   var i = 1;

    var onAddTab = function(tabPanel) {
        var newTab = {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Untitled Tab ' + (i++)
        };

        var index = tabPanel.items.length - 1;
        var newTabItem = tabPanel.insert(index, newTab);

        tabPanel.setActiveTab(newTabItem);
    };

    var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
        listeners: {
            beforetabchange: function(tabs, newTab, oldTab, eOpts) {
                if (newTab.title == 'Add') {
                    onAddTab(tabPanel);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
        items: [{
            title: 'Default Tab',
            html: 'Hello World'
        }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            title: 'Add',
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```